# How should these questions about temporary hit points/Armor of Agathys (that are currently marked as duplicates) be handled?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, closed-questions, duplicates

This meta question was prompted by the following 3 questions on mainsite (mainly the first two):

1. [Do multiple sources of Temporary Hit Points combine or do you only get one set?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69488/do-multiple-sources-of-temporary-hit-points-combine-or-do-you-only-get-one-set)
2. [How does Armor of Agathys interact with getting temporary hit points?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55751/how-does-armor-of-agathys-interact-with-getting-temporary-hit-points)
3. [Dark One's Blessing and Armor of Agathys Synergy?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65587/dark-ones-blessing-and-armor-of-agathys-synergy)

Currently, #1 and #3 are both closed as duplicates of #2.

However, question #1 seems to ask more about the general case, and simply uses *armor of Agathys* and False Life as examples of that general question. In contrast, question #2 specifically asks about *armor of Agathys* (including in the title), and about what happens to the effect of *armor of Agathys* (i.e. if you're hit with a melee attack, the other creature takes damage) if the character gains another source of temporary hit points as well. Question #3 seems fairly similar to #2, in that it asks about the effect of *armor of Agathys* if another source of temp HP is gained.

My initial thought was to wonder if #1 and #2 should be merged (into #1). If they were truly duplicates of one another, then #1 asks about the general case whereas #2 is more specific, so it would make more sense to have the dupe target be the general one. I was thinking that the answers to the #1 and #2 also both address the general case, since there is a general rule. Under this interpretation, #1 would remain the final version, #2 would be merged into it (its answers copied over). I'm unsure if #3 would then be left as a duplicate of the remaining question (#1).

However, upon rereading, a different interpretation occurred to me:
Perhaps question #2 isn't quite a duplicate of #1. #2 specifically asks whether the damaging effect of *armor of Agathys* if you get temp HP from another source, whereas #1 simply asks if they stack (#2 seems like it potentially already assumes they don't stack). If this interpretation is correct, then it seems like question #1 should simply be reopened. Question #3 also assumes they don't stack and would stay a dupe of #2, since question #3 is a specific subset of #2.

I'm not positive which interpretation is correct. Thus, I decided to ask here on meta.

**What should be done about these three questions about temp HP?**

- Should #1 and #2 be merged into #1, which would cause its answers to
  be copied over? (If so, would #3 be left as a dupe of the remaining
  question?)
- Should question #1 simply be reopened, leaving the other two
  questions as-is? (This is what I'm leaning towards after some
  thought.)
- Should all the questions be left as-is?
- Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say reopen #1 and leave #2 and #3 as is. I believe you were correct with your interpretation as mentioned in the "rereading" paragraph. However #3 is attempting to clarify if the damage from AoA is only valid with the THP granted by AoA or if it works with any THP.

Comment: I've finally gone ahead and reopened question #1.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be left as-is. The answer to #2 is correct for #1 and for #3.

Comment: Relevant metas: [Non-duplicate question with answer in another question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5019/33569), [If an answer to question A can be found in question B, should we close A as duplicate of B?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7523/33569), [How to deal with multiple questions that have effectively the same answer?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5050/33569). In short, whether questions are duplicates depends on whether the *question* is the same, not whether the *answer* is the same. And in this case, I'm not sure the questions are the same.

Comment: In particular, as I note, questions #2 and #3 ask about Armor of Agathys' secondary damaging effect. #2 just asks whether AoA's effect ends if the character gets temp HP from another source, implying they already know temp HP doesn't stack; #3 even explicitly notes that temp HP doesn't stack. As such, it doesn't seem like either of them are quite duplicates of #1 to me. What #1 is asking is not about the damage done to the attacker by *armor of Agathys*; it's just being used as an example of a source that is granting temp HP, with nothing about its secondary effect.